# TCP Communicator Application?

Tags: debugging, networking, tcp

I am looking for software to help debug client/server software.

I am looking for an application where I can simply connect to a remote host on a given port and send it bytes of data and observe the responses.

Is there such software existing?

Comment: May be Wireshark will meet your needs: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools

Comment: Also try the beloved telnet. I would use it for this.

Comment: Can you expand a bit? For instance, are you looking to see what ports are open on the remote host (port scan tools)? Are you running any applications on the host that would open the ports you wish to scan? Without something opening the port on the remote host, you will not connect. Is TCP the only requirement, or do you need other layer-4 protocols (UDP, etc.), too?

Comment: Recommendation questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use netcat. There are many [different implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Ports_and_reimplementations). This is the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) for BSD's netcat.

Answer (score 0):

nodejs do have an high level tcp api you can use to create a 5lines script that wee do the job for you

```
var net= require('net');
var sock = net.connect(1234, '127.0.0.1', function(){
  sock.write(new Buffer("some binary data here"));
  sock.write(new Buffer([0,1,2])); // 3 more bytes
  sock.on("data", function(buffer) {
     console.log("Server response is ", buffer); // display raw response buffer
  })
});
```